# jQuery inserting a page into div breaks javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, reload

My index.php has a jquery ajax call that inserts getposts.php into my #content div. This works fine.. The problem is that getposts.php has some javascript (more jQuery) in it and while Chrome does execute the code fine, Firefox doesn't.

If I include the javascript as a file (setchecked.js) firebug is looking for setchecked.js_=1322020697832

If I include the javascript directly into getposts.php, the javascript is completely ignored (it doesn't even show up in the source code)

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fetchposts.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

fetchposts.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'getposts.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (fetched) {
        $('#content').load('getposts.php');
    },
});
});
```

getposts.php (this makes firebug look for setchecked.js_=1322020697832

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="setchecked.js"></script>
```

or getposts.php (the javascript is completely absent from the source code)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// set $checked values
$.ajax({
    url: 'query.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        ------ do some fun stuff that works --------
    },
});
});
</script>
         --------------- some php and html that DOES display -------------
```

Again, my problem isn't the content of my javascript, but how to get the javascript to work within the #content. Chrome does execute the code without problem. For some reason, it is firefox being picky. Firebug reports no errors, other than looking for the wrong file or completely ignoring it.

The rest of getposts.php (the html and php code) DOES display inside my #content in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: To ask the dumb question: if your first bit of Ajax is calling into a PHP script, why are you trying to include a bit of JavaScript that just runs another Ajax call? Would it not be easier to just call `query.php` within `getposts.php`?

Comment: No. The ajax calling to query.php fetches an array from a different database and executes some jQuery using that info to alter the classes of some divs inside getposts.php. This output then gets inserted into the #content through the ajax calling to getposts.php. 

Even if I include query.php in getposts.php, I still have to execute more jQuery on it to alter the div classes.

That brings us back to square one.

If I include the javascript from setchecked.js into my index.php, it will not execute on what gets inserted into #content and so #content would only contain the unmodified div classes.

Comment: What is it that you are needing to get from the separate database? Can you be specific?

Comment: I figured out the problem! the ajax calling to getposts.php executes on success the load of getposts.php. By removing the ajax code and simply leaving the load, the javascript functions perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the scripts are working, but I think that they need some refactoring.
From the code I see that you are

1. Loading content from getposts.php into the #content
2. Once loaded, you want to get some JSON
3. When JSON is loaded, you want to some fun stuff with it

The code can be improved by:

- Not making so many ajax calls
- Using specialized, ajax methods specifically for each task
- Putting them within a single file

fetchposts.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var someFunStuff = function(msg) {
        // do some fun stuff that works 
    };

    var setChecked = function() {
        $.getJSON('query.php', someFunStuff);
    };

    $('#content').load('getposts.php', setChecked);
});
```

If I've misunderstood something that you want to get done or you have some more specifications that need to be introduced, let me know and I will respond as needed.

### Update

I see a comment that you've made about using a single javascript file.  What is it that you are needing to get from the separate database?

Comment: your answer led me to realize that my ajax executed the load on success when all I needed was the load without the ajax. Simply using load without the ajax allows getposts.php to execute its javascript.

Comment: I actually didnt' think it would automatically execute the js. :)